# Input integers from CSV file( graph adjacency list) in C

Tags: c, graph

I'm trying to implement the BFS algorithm to determine the shortest path between two nodes.For that I have been given the graph as an input csv file which is the adjacency list.I plan to store this list as an array of struct "rel" and get input from the file shown in the code.However, the output doesn't show the correct values.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct relation // to store the pair of integers in a csv file line (c connected to y
{
    int x;
    int y;
}rel; // relation

void split(char* buffer,char* string1,char* string2) // spilts buffer into two strings seperated by ,
{
    char* buffer_trav = buffer; // trav ptr in buffer
    char* string_trav = string1; // trav ptr to string 1 or 2(after ',' is read)
    while(*buffer_trav!='\0')
    {
        if(*buffer_trav==',')
        {
            string_trav = string2;
            buffer_trav+=1;
            
        }
        else
        {
            *string_trav = *buffer_trav;
            string_trav+=1;
            buffer_trav+=1;
                
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("graph.csv","r"); // reading csv file 
    
    int max_number_data  = 100; // maximum number of edge relations in the file
    rel graph[max_number_data];

    for(int i=0;i<max_number_data;i++)
    {
        graph[i].x=1 ;
        graph[i].y=-1 ;     // setting initial value to be used as a check point for other functions
    }

    char buffer[10];//buffer for input
    char x_buffer[5];// buffer for name
    char y_buffer[5]; // buffer for password

    int count=0;
    while(fgets(buffer,10,fp)!=NULL)                                                                
    {
        char* ptr; // to be used to convert string to integer;
        split(buffer,x_buffer,y_buffer); // splits into two strings

        printf("%s : %s;\n",x_buffer,y_buffer);  // To debug

        graph[count].x = (int)strtol(x_buffer,&ptr,10); // converts string to longint which is later cat into int
        graph[count].y = (int)strtol(y_buffer,&ptr,10); //  " " " " " " " " " " " " "" " " " " "" " "" "" " " "" 
        count++;                                


    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Input file:

```
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
0,5
0,6
0,7
0,8
0,10
0,11
0,12
0,13
0,17
0,19
0,21
0,31
1,0
1,2
1,3
1,7
1,13
1,17
1,19
1,21
1,30
2,0
2,1
2,3
2,7
2,8
2,9
2,13
2,27
2,28
2,32
3,0
3,1
3,2
3,7
3,12
3,13
4,0
4,6
4,10
5,0
5,6
5,10
5,16
6,0
6,4
6,5
6,16
7,0
7,1
7,2
7,3
8,0
8,2
8,30
8,32
8,33
9,2
9,33
10,0
10,4
10,5
11,0
12,0
12,3
13,0
13,1
13,2
13,3
13,33
14,32
14,33
15,32
15,33
16,5
16,6
17,0
17,1
18,32
18,33
19,0
19,1
19,33
20,32
20,33
21,0
21,1
22,32
22,33
23,25
23,27
23,29
23,32
23,33
24,25
24,27
24,31
25,23
25,24
25,31
26,29
26,33
27,2
27,23
27,24
27,33
28,2
28,31
28,33
29,23
29,26
29,32
29,33
30,1
30,8
30,32
30,33
31,0
31,24
31,25
31,28
31,32
31,33
32,2
32,8
32,14
32,15
32,18
32,20
32,22
32,23
32,29
32,30
32,31
32,33
33,8
33,9
33,13
33,14
33,15
33,18
33,19
33,20
33,22
33,23
33,26
33,27
33,28
33,29
33,30
33,31
33,32
```

The output( Debugging ) I get is:

```
0`@?d : 1
;
0`@?d : 2
;
0`@?d : 3
;
0`@?d : 4
;
0`@?d : 5
;
0`@?d : 6
;
0`@?d : 7
;
0`@?d : 8
;
0`@?d : 10
;
0`@?d : 11
;
0`@?d : 12
;
0`@?d : 13
;
0`@?d : 17
;
0`@?d : 19
;
0`@?d : 21
;
0`@?d : 31
;
1`@?d : 0

;
1`@?d : 2

;
1`@?d : 3

;
1`@?d : 7

;
1`@?d : 13
;
1`@?d : 17
;
1`@?d : 19
;
1`@?d : 21
;
1`@?d : 30
;
2`@?d : 0

;
2`@?d : 1

;
2`@?d : 3

;
2`@?d : 7

;
2`@?d : 8

;
2`@?d : 9

;
2`@?d : 13
;
2`@?d : 27
;
2`@?d : 28
;
2`@?d : 32
;
3`@?d : 0

;
3`@?d : 1

;
3`@?d : 2

;
3`@?d : 7

;
3`@?d : 12
;
3`@?d : 13
;
4`@?d : 0

;
4`@?d : 6

;
4`@?d : 10
;
5`@?d : 0

;
5`@?d : 6

;
5`@?d : 10
;
5`@?d : 16
;
6`@?d : 0

;
6`@?d : 4

;
6`@?d : 5

;
6`@?d : 16
;
7`@?d : 0

;
7`@?d : 1

;
7`@?d : 2

;
7`@?d : 3

;
8`@?d : 0

;
8`@?d : 2

;
8`@?d : 30
;
8`@?d : 32
;
8`@?d : 33
;
9`@?d : 2

;
9`@?d : 33
;
10@?d : 0

;
10@?d : 4

;
10@?d : 5

;
11@?d : 0

;
12@?d : 0

;
12@?d : 3

;
13@?d : 0

;
13@?d : 1

;
13@?d : 2

;
13@?d : 3

;
13@?d : 33
;
14@?d : 32
;
14@?d : 33
;
15@?d : 32
;
15@?d : 33
;
16@?d : 5

;
16@?d : 6

;
17@?d : 0

;
17@?d : 1

;
18@?d : 32
;
18@?d : 33
;
19@?d : 0

;
19@?d : 1

;
19@?d : 33
;
20@?d : 32
;
20@?d : 33
;
21@?d : 0

;
21@?d : 1

;
22@?d : 32
;
22@?d : 33
;
23@?d : 25
;
23@?d : 27
;
23@?d : 29
;
23@?d : 32
;
23@?d : 33
;
24@?d : 25
;
24@?d : 27
;
24@?d : 31
;
25@?d : 23
;
25@?d : 24
;
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? For starters one error is that the strings are not being NUL terminated.

Comment: This stuff is soooo much easier in C++  Why limit yourself to such a creaky old language?

Comment: I have to finish this within a day and I'm unsure if I can do it If I have to get started with c++ (never used it) now. So sticking with C.

Comment: Do you understand the second part of my comment? Strings in c need to end with a nul character.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm changing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that strings were not terminated with null characters.Also, the segmentation fault occurred because while the csv file had around 200 lines, I initiated maximum input lines to 100.